# Bluez 5 migration. DiscoverServices does not exist

Tags: linux, bluetooth, dbus, bluez

I'm porting an application from Bluez 4 to Bluez 5 using DBus capabilities. In the Bluez 4, I checked remote services presence using the `Device.DiscoverServices(..)` method. Right now, I don't see any direct replacement in Bluez 5. As a solution, it might be a good idea to use the `UUIDs` property from the Device1 group, but I'm not sure whether they are the same since now it returns 128-bit UUIDs list and before we had 8/16-bit handles.

Here is part of the documentation from Bluez 4.

> DiscoverServices returns a dictionary with the record handles as keys and the service record in XML format as values. The key is uint32, and the value a is a string for this dictionary.

And the information returned by `StartDiscovery(..)` method

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<record>
    <attribute id="0x0000">
        <uint32 value="0x00010018" />
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0001">
        <sequence>
            <uuid value="0x1105" />
        </sequence>
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0004">
        <sequence>
            <sequence>
                <uuid value="0x0100" />
            </sequence>
            <sequence>
                <uuid value="0x0003" />
                <uint8 value="0x04" />
            </sequence>
            <sequence>
                <uuid value="0x0008" />
            </sequence>
        </sequence>
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0005">
        <sequence>
            <uuid value="0x1002" />
        </sequence>
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0100">
        <text value="OBEX Object Push" />
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0303">
        <sequence>
            <uint8 value="0xff" />
        </sequence>
    </attribute>
</record>
```

And here is a Bluez 5.

> org.bluez.Device1
> Properties
> array{string} UUIDs [readonly, optional]
> List of 128-bit UUIDs that represents the available remote services.

So, how can I get remote services in the right way using Bluez 5 and DBus? Perhaps I'm looking for solutions like the output from the `sdptool browse` and `Protocol Descriptor List` fields. Still, in my case, I see only discovered UUIDs without any additional information.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: What is it you want to do with this information? There might be more people that can help do what you want in BlueZ 5.

Comment: For example, I would like to correctly set a channel based on discovered service information. E.g., Client1.CreateSession(..) receives a dictionary with the channel to connect. Using Bluez 4 I was able to discover available services and fetch their active channel. As for Bluez 5, I don't know how to correctly discover service channel.

Comment: In the examples in the BlueZ source tree they do not specify the channel of the discovered device. For example: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/ftp-client
 Once the session is created you can get the channel with [session properties](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/obex-api.txt)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with BueZ 4 but reading the [BlueZ 5 API introduction and porting guide](http://www.bluez.org/bluez-5-api-introduction-and-porting-guide/) it says the following:

> Because most tasks of managing and discovering objects can be done
> through ObjectManager many methods, signals and properties in BlueZ 4
> became redundant and were decided to be removed.

So I suspect that the specific command has been replaced with the generic D-Bus `GetManagedObjects` method.